# Handling project files when multiple users are commiting

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm not sure what the workflow is supposed to be when working with other users that are  making changes to repository.

Here's my situation: The repository is initially created by a colleague and he makes the first commit. I ended up using git clone to get the project onto my computer to work on. After working on the project, he commits a bunch of updated files.

Now, the repository is different from what I have locally. I have not committed my own changes yet as I do not know what the best way is to proceed. Do I commit and whatever changes I made automatically get added to the file along with my colleague's changes? However, locally I do not have the updated files from the repository...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch changes from the remote repository so that your local repository can know them.
You can do either

`git fetch origin`

to fetch the changes, look around and then merge/rebase. Or:

`git pull` with optional `--rebase`.

This way you will merge or rebase your local changes on top of the incomming changes from the upstream.

Comment: So to be clear, let's say the original files had A, my changes are A+B, and the master currently is A+C (my colleague's updates). If I Pull, then it merges A+C with my local A+B, giving me A+B+C, which is what I want. In the repository it is still A+C after the merge, so when I commit it becomes A+B+C?

Comment: Yes, a simple merge using ``git pull`` will give you what you want. However, to keep the history cleaner you might want to use ``git pull --rebase`` most of the time. It will rebase your local changes on top of the remote branch.

Comment: Should I commit my changes first before doing a pull?

Comment: Yes, sure. Otherwise you may encounter problems if a complicated merge is required.